# c++ regex: MS VS 2013 output differs from online "c++ 2014 live code" output

Tags: c++, regex

EDIT: Never mind. It works now. Who knows. I'm banging my head against the wall.

When the following code is run in MS Visual Studio Express 2013, it doesn't work, and the original string is printed unmodified.
When the code is run online, using "C++ 2014", it is correct, and the '*' is added between the ')' and the '9.'  What's going on?

Live Code is available at [ideone.com/2mq4u3](http://ideone.com/2mq4u3).

```
std::string ss ("1 + (3+2)9 - 2 ");
std::regex ee ("(\\)\\d)([^ ])");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, ")*$1");
std::cout << result;
```

Live Code output: `1 + (3+2)*9 - 2`

MS VC 2013 output: `1 + (3+2)9 - 2`

Comment: It works, and the output is `1 + (3+2)*9 - 2 `, the regex must be `static const std::regex ee ("\\)(\\d)");`. You just failed to copy it from the site to your code, right?

Comment: No.  Somebody else posted that live code as a solution to my problem, but that code doesn't work on my laptop.  You are saying you are getting the correct output with MS Visual Studio Express 2013?  I just installed VC++, for this project, and it literally took hours for it to install itself.  I can't imagine anything is already corrupted.

Comment: Never mind.  It works now.  Who knows.  I'm banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working in Visual Studio:

```
std::string ss ("1 + (3+2)9 - 2 ");
std::regex ee ("\\)(\\d)");

std::string result;
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), ss.begin(), ss.end(), ee, ")*$1");
std::cout << result;
```

Console window:

[image]

Actually, you could just use:

```
std::regex ee("\\)(\\d)");
std::string result = std::regex_replace (ss, ee, ")*$1");
```

You will get the same output.

Here is the list of includes I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
```